# How to print extended ASCII characters to WSL2 Ubuntu console?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, wsl-2, extended-ascii

For some reason whenever I try to print out extended ascii characters such as `192U` which is the left corner symbol, the console shows the following characters:
[image]

Normal ascii characters print with no problems.

Is there any way to print/enable extended ascii characters on Ubuntu WSL2?

Comment: Is WSL2 supporting UFT-8? I'd make sure that I'd be writing UTF-8. That's how the Gnome terminal works, at least.

Comment: Agree with @AlexisWilke.  See the mapping of CP437 Extended ASCII to UTF-8 codes at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).  For your example, the left-bottom box character would be \u2514.

Comment: WSL2 terminal and Ubuntu support UTF8. Please use that, rather than antiquated and inadequate Windows code pages (some people call those "extended ASCII").